# Makefile: Manage multiple include path

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project with this kind of tree:

```
/arch/arm/include/    
/include/
```

I want to include files from `/arch/arm/include/` with `#include <arch/header.h>` and 
 files from `/include` with `#include <header.h>`.

How to do this in a Makefile ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be solved by creating a symbolic link include/arch that points to arch/arm/include
ln -s arch/arm/include include/arch

then in the makefile:
CFLAGS += -I/include

Answer (score 0):

Use `-I< include directory >` option. 
**ex:**

```
$(CC) -o $(TGT) test.c -I/include
```

Comment: Will this work if the OP has included the files from `/arch/arm/include/`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method in your makefile. Assuming your filesystem looks like this

```
   --------------------------------                                                    
   |                 |           |
include            arch         src  
                    |             |
                   arm          makefile
                    |
                  include
```

LIBS_INC = -I../include
LIBS_INC += -I../arch/arm/include